# AWK concatenate strings

Tags: awk

I have a test file with following content:

```
k1:v1
```

I'd like to get `v1` and concatenate with a string `a` using AWK command below:

`cat test.txt | grep k1 | awk -F: '{print $2"a"}'`

Expected the result is `v1a`, but I got `a1`. If I concatenate with `aa`, then I got `aa`. Seems like it overwrites the string `v1` from beginning. I have been debugging for a long time, I cannot see any reason to cause this.

Comment: I could not reproduce it, for me it works...Is that the exact string?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. We could do it in a single `awk` itself we need not to use `grep` and `cat` with it. Simply make field separator as `:` and check condition if line starts from `K1` then print 2nd field along with string `a` then.

```
awk -F':' '/^k1/{print $2"a"}' Input_file
```

Comment: Check with `cat -v Input_file` in case you have control M characters in your file, if yes; then try `awk -F':' '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /^k1/{print $2"a"}' Input_file` to remove them and then Process awk command further.